# Access function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, function

I would to be able to use functions whose I can see the code, which are used in built-in matlab functions but which I cannot directly call.

One of these functions is `checkdata`. I can see the code of this function. It ìs used in built-in matlab functions like `gmdistribution.fit` but I cannot directly call it by doing

```
X = zeros(5,5);
checkdata(X)
```

**How could I call these functions in my own functions?**

Comment: it is a private function, you can see its code by looking at the path to the m-file of the calling function, where you will find a folder called private.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not call the function `checkdata` because it is a private function. To make a function private to a file, you have to store the function file in a folder called `private`. For example consider the following folder structure:

```
-Folder A
   - m1.m
   - m2.m
   Folder private
      - privatefunction1.m
      - privatefunction2.m
Folder B
   - m3.m
```

m1.m and m2.m can call privatefunction1.m and privatefunction2.m. m3.m can not call any of these two private functions. For more details go to [Matlab help about private functions](http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/matlab/matlab_prog/private-functions.html).

However, if you want to use `checkdata`, you can locate checkdata.m and copy it to an other folder.

Comment: bear in mind that toolbox functions are copyrighted material.

Comment: You're right. But I don't think the copyright is different for private functions than for other functions, is it? So you have to give attention to that anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the m-file which has this function in `MATLABFOLDER\toolbox\stats\stats\@gmdistribution\private`. This is matlabs way of making functions private([see here](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/matlab_prog/private-functions.html)).  Matlab does not allow you to add private folders such as this one to your path. 
The simple workaround is to place your own m-file with a similar function somewere in your path, which is not to hard to do since you are able to look at the code and what it does. When doing so I would recommend to avoid naming conficts. matlab handles those [like this](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/matlab_prog/function-precedence-order.html).

Comment: Yeah but having to copy existing functions to a new file to make them work is non-sense to me